# Certain polynomials monotone on [-1:1]?

Tags: polynomials

I'm in the process of reading a paper and I believe there's a mistake, but it could also be me not noticing something.

Here's the deal:

Let $\bar\Pi_k$ be the set of all polynomials of degree at most $k$ that satisfy $p(1) = 1$.

Next, let $\mu_i, i = 1...n$ be a finite set of numbers in the open interval $(-1,1)$.

In one of the proofs in the paper, they appear to make the following assumption:
If $p \in \bar\Pi$, then
$$ \max_i\, p^2(\mu_i) \le p^2(\max_i\, | \mu_i |)$$

However, I find absolutely no reason for this to be true. Note: The coefficients of the polynomials are not guaranteed to be non-negative, otherwise s.th. like Jensen's inequality might have done the trick.

Comment: Your title says that the polynomials are monotone but the body doesn't.

Comment: Well, if the polynomials 'were' monotone, then the statement would be true, wouldn't it? So that's what I was wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: $p(X)=2-X^2$ then $p(0)\geq p(x)$ for all $x\in(-1,1)$. The same property is true for $p^2$. One can check that $p(1)=1$. Take $\mu_0=0$ and $\mu_1$ whatever value different from zero to get a couterexample.

Comment: Do you mean $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$?

Comment: @trevor. $0$ is the maximum of $p^2$, any finite set with $0$ (i.e. $\{0,\mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots\}$) is a couterexample

Comment: I really should start looking for examples first, before trying to prove something :D

Comment: @Lagerbaer. ;) 

Remark that the result is true if the coefficients are non-negative. In this case $p^2(x)$ has non-negative coefficients and a triangular inequality gives you the result.